# Is there a useful purpose for <style type="text/javascript">?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, dreamweaver

What is the use and purpose this , is it useful?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's for "JSSS", or *Javascript style sheets*; see **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Style_Sheets)** for more info. It's nonstandard and never really caught on outside of Netscape's original proposal, which you can read **[here](http://www.w3.org/Submission/1996/1/WD-jsss-960822)**. I don't think most browsers today support this; I've certainly never seen a website that used it.

Comment: In fact, only supported in NS4.

Comment: Good lord, that’s right. I’d completely forgotten about that odd little branch of web development history.

Just think, if that had caught on, jQuery might never need to have been written.

Comment: What, JSSS gives you the `$()` function?

Comment: it's strange if it's so old and outdated then why still dreamweaver has support

Comment: @Jitendra » I guess that's the million-dollar question, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

i believe its bug. "text/javascript shall be associated only with script tag not style tag!

Answer (score 0):

Both `<style></style>` and `<script></script>` can be used without any 'type' attribute. Probably a sticky web tradition.

Comment: Good idea to always include them, though, since they're required in strict doctypes.

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, all browsers besides NS4 will ignore the block of code, when the type is unrecognized. Perhaps not important for the Style tag, but useful for the Script tag..

See more about templating with this at http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Answer (score 0):

Style type can not be "text/javascript".
It should be only "text/css".